# Selecting the most recently added record to the database in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in database which has a primary key called id. Now i want to display the most recently added 2 records into the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This wil definitely work,

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC,LIMIT 2.
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming id is some sort of auto-incrementing integer value then the following will work

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2;
```

If you want just the last inserted record id (again assuming the insert generates an autoincrement id) there is also [LAST_INSERT_ID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id). But beware this is global and will return last inserted id database-wide so it is not often used in SELECTS but rather as an OUT paramer in a routine to return the id of the just-inserted row.

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```sql
SELECT * FROM `table`
ORDER BY id 
DESC 
LIMIT 0, 2;
```